# Application crash when JSONValue unable to read json iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

My Application crash when JSONValue unable to read json iphone?

here what i m getting

```
Response [{"profile_pic":"1.jpg","user_name":"Jack"}]
2011-02-17 13:37:38.209 App[3964:207] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object key string expected\" UserInfo=0x6057070 {NSLocalizedDescription=Object key string expected}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Expected value while parsing array\" UserInfo=0x6057120 {NSUnderlyingError=0x60570d0 \"Object key string expected\", NSLocalizedDescription=Expected value while parsing array}"
)
```

Comment: Your JSON string is valid. Are you using the latest SBJSON version?

Comment: If JSONValue failed it will return a nil. So do a check in your code to prevent crash.

Comment: @bavarious Yes i m using SBJSON application crash when i send multiple request on server by changing view iphone

Comment: @diwup i just checked NSLog(@"json value %@",[responseString JSONValue]);
  if ([responseString JSONValue]==NULL) {
   NSLog(@"in check"); 
  }  but still crash  i just check json  here what i get [NSCFString appendData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60e2230

Answer (score 0):

hey i tried with your input and got through

```
NSLog(@"%@", [@"[{\"profile_pic\":\"1.jpg\",\"user_name\":\"Jack\"}]" JSONValue]);
```

[Session started at 2011-02-17 14:38:48 +0500.]

**2011-02-17 14:38:49.970 iJSON[3349:207]**

```
(
        {
        "profile_pic" = "1.jpg";
        "user_name" = Jack;
    }
)
```